# Attempted regex of string that contains multiple numbers as different base counts

Tags: python, regex, string

Currently building an encryption module in python 3.8 and have run into a snag with a desired feature/upgrade. Looking for some assistance in finding a solution that would be more helpful than writing  a 'string crawler' to parse out an encrypted string of data.

In my first 'official' release everything works fine, but this is due to how much easier it is to split a string based of off easily identifiable prefixes in a string. For example, '0x' in a hexadecimal or '0o' in an octal.

The current definitions for what a number can inhabit use the aforementioned base types along with support for counts of 2-10 as '{n}bXX'.

What I currently have implemented works just fine for the present design, but having trouble with trying to come up with something that can handle higher bases (at least up to 64) that isn't going to be bulky or slow; also, the redesign is having trouble parsing out a string which contains multiple base counts, post assignment to their corresponding characters.

TL;DR - If I have an encoded string like so: "0x9a0o25179b83629b86740xc01d64b9HM-70o5521"
I would like it to be split as: [0x9a, 0o2517, 9b8362, 9b8674, 0xc0ld, 64b9HM-7, 0o5521]
and need help finding a better solution than: r'(?:0x)|(?:9b)|...'

Comment: So you want to match `0o` followed by any number greater than 0 of digits `0-7`, or `0x` followed by any number greater than 0 of characters `0-9a-fA-F`, or `(?:[2-9]|10)b` followed by any number greater than 0 of digits? Regexes almost write themselves. https://regex101.com/r/SlGRxn/1

Comment: @Grismar: reminds me of the saying _"If you have a problem you need to solve with regex, you then have two problems"_ They don't write themselves and are very error prone. However, your solution works and I found it interesting to analyze, thanks for sharing! :)

Comment: You want to use different "Number Bases Conversion" systems starting from binary until Base 64, which includes all in the middle such as ternary, quaternary, quinary and so on. Why do you have "-" in Base 64? I mean this 64b9HM-7

Comment: @Grismar, Thank you for the new book mark, that may come in handy in the future. Agreed, regexes do almost write themselves, but this one has been a headache for a week now. So, quite frankly yes, I'm looking for something that can parse one or any combination of the three, or more depending on the number of sub keys the user defines.

Comment: @rcastellcastell, still looking into what a base 64 actually contains but needed an example to get the point across, but yes to the rest of your question as well. The end product for the module should have support for binary-64 and everything in between

Comment: Your encryption format doesn't seem consistent (or there're hidden rules). Let's say you have `7b12345b123` what will be the result ? `['7b1234', '5b123']` or `['7b123', '45b123']`?

Comment: Pardon the pun, but definitely trying to be cryptic here... this being said the project is public on GitHub. Actually, thanks to Grismar, the issue has been resolved until further testing in phase 2 of the current feature/maintenance